# List contents changing with each iteration

Tags: python

So I am working on making a dictionary of subway stations in Boston and their neighbors for a bigger program. Each station belongs to a line, like blue or red, and these lines make up the whole entire subway system in Boston. But I am having trouble. here is my code so far:

```
 for i in range(len(tuples)):

    for x in range(len(tuples[i][1])):

        print tuples
        neighbors=[]
        station=tuples[i][1][x]
        if tuples[i][1][-1]==station and station not in duplicates:
            line=0
            for item in tuples:
                if station in item[1]:
                    line=item[0]
                    break
            neighbors.append((tuples[i][1][-2],line))
        elif tuples[i][1][0]==station and station not in duplicates:
            line=0
            for item in tuples:
                if station in item[1]:
                    line=item[0]
                    break
            neighbors.append((tuples[i][1][1],line)) 
        elif station in duplicates:
            line=[]
            for item in tuples:
                if station in item[1]:
                    line.append((item[0],tuples.index(item)))
            neighbors=[(tuples[i][1][x+1],tuples[i][1][x-1],line[0][0]),(tuples[line[1][1]][1][x+1],tuples[line[1][1]][1][x-1],line[1][0])]
        else:
            line=0
            for item in tuples:
                if station in item[1]:
                    line=item[0]
                    break
            neighbors.append((tuples[i][1][x+1],tuples[i][1][x-1],line[0][0])) 
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            subdict[station]={}
            for i in range(len(neighbor)-1):
              subdict[station].update({neighbor[i]:neighbor[-1]})
```

So I ran it and got a syntax error indicating an index out of range error. This made no sense but then I printed out the individual stations and lists in tuple, and found that they kept changing. So in one iteration, the list of stations in one subway line was the same as expected, but then after that it was completely different. Only the first station in the list in one subway line remained the same; the rest were from different lines of the Boston subway.

So can someone tell me whats going on in my code?

Comment: Do you have some example data? What line triggered the error? Why are you iterating over the tuples by index instead of iterating directly over its elements?

Comment: You should define a `Station` class with properties like line and neighbors (the list of linked stations and direction). A linked list should be more appropriate representation for this kind of data than a complex nested lists of lists.

Comment: Please be more specific with the details of the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in the last few lines:

```
for i in range(len(tuples)):
    for x in range(len(tuples[i][1])):
        [...]
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            for i in range(len(neighbor)-1): #<- HERE
            [...]
```

Your outer loop is iterating over the index of tuples and stores this index in the variable `i`. The nested loop at the end overwrites this variable with another value, which is certainly not what you want.

Comment: That's another problem. Well spotted!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without example data, and because your data structure appears to be very convoluted at first glance.

But there is one thing that makes me suspicious:

- You're iterating `x` over `range(len(tuples[i][1]))`.
- Then you do `neighbors=[(tuples[i][1][x+1],...)]`.

That appears likely to throw an `Index out of bounds` exception.